# Using Tailwind to position content off screen

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I am trying to learn Tailwind and I am trying to position content off the page, so for this example I am trying to make a duplicate of this page: https://bravepeople.co I was able to get this far:

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<section id="home" class="main pt-24 md:pt-48 flex flex-wrap flex-col md:flex-row">
  <div class="flex flex-col w-full xl:w-5/12 justify-center lg:items-start overflow-y-hidden">
    <h1 class="my-4 text-3xl md:text-5xl font-bold leading-tight text-center md:text-left">Main Title</h1>
    <p class="leading-normal text-base md:text-2xl mb-8 text-center md:text-left">Sub-title message</p>
  </div>

  <div class="w-full xl:w-7/12 py-6 overflow-y-hidden">
    <div class="flex gap-4">
      <div class="flex-initial">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/345x580" class="img-container_image">
      </div>
      <div class="flex-initial">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/345x580" class="img-container_image">
      </div>
      <div class="flex-initial">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/345x580" class="img-container_image">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

How can I adjust this so part of the last box is off the page? Thanks!

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the tour first: https://stackoverflow.com/tour -> then please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask -> Please note, that SO is neither a tutorial, guide or forum. IMHO this questions lacks basic research efford. However to give you the right hint: `width: >100%;` + `overflow: hidden;` are the the tools you will need here.

Comment: @tacoshy thanks! Tried that, still no luck. Definitely not looking for a tutorial or a guide, but simply an answer to my question.

Comment: they use multiple elements with a height of 100vh and width of 100vw lines up next to each other. Then disabled horizontal scrolling by using `overflow: hidden` and do the scrolling with a script and scroll-snap. They way they do it is quite advanced as it requires a good portion of scripting and that blows the purpose on questions that should be asked on SO.

Comment: @tacoshy - dude please throw me an example!

Answer (score 0):

i used relative and added a css with minus 100 pixels

https://play.tailwindcss.com/kMCMEiMZNK?layout=horizontal

```
.righto {
  right: -100px;
}


<section id="home" class="flex flex-row relative ">

            <div class="w-1/4">
                <h1 class="my-4 text-3xl md:text-5xl font-bold leading-tight text-center md:text-left">Main Title</h1>
                <p class="leading-normal text-base md:text-2xl mb-8 text-center md:text-left">Sub-title message</p>
            </div>
            
            <div class="bg-red-200 w-5/6 absolute top-0 righto  ">
                <div class="flex flex-row justify-end  ">
                    <div class="mr-10">
                        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/345x580" class="img-container_image">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mr-10">
                        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/345x580" class="img-container_image">
                    </div>
                    <div class="  ">
                        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/345x580" class="img-container_image">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </section>
```

Comment: Doesn't give the proper effect at all... even in the example?

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be simple as:

```html
<div class="absolute -top-full -left-full"></div>
```